# Cast as date after strtok_split_to_table

Tags: sql, teradata

In this query :

```
        SELECT 
            CAST(STRTOK(MY_STRTOK.new_line,';', 1 ) AS BIGINT) AS ID_EXPR, 
            CAST(STRTOK(MY_STRTOK.new_line,';', 2 ) AS DATE) AS DT_DEBT_VALD_CNT_FORM
        FROM TABLE (STRTOK_SPLIT_TO_TABLE(1, '83001590;2016-01-01¤', '¤')
             RETURNS (serialno INTEGER
                     ,rownum INTEGER
                     , new_line VARCHAR(32000)  CHARACTER SET UNICODE)
                     ) AS MY_STRTOK
```

It returns an error when I add the cast as date for the second field.
What can be the reason ?

the error :

> SELECT Failed. 3707:  Syntax error, expected something like ')'
>   between the 'INT' keyword and the 'FORMAT' keyword.

Fix :

```
        SELECT 
            CAST(STRTOK(MY_STRTOK.new_line,';', 1 ) AS BIGINT) AS ID_EXPR, 
            CAST(STRTOK(MY_STRTOK.new_line,';', 2 ) AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYY/MM/DD') AS DT_DEBT_VALD_CNT_FORM
        FROM TABLE (STRTOK_SPLIT_TO_TABLE(1, '83001590;2016-01-01¤', '¤')
             RETURNS (serialno INTEGER
                     ,rownum INTEGER
                     , new_line VARCHAR(32000)  CHARACTER SET UNICODE)
                     ) AS MY_STRTOK
```

Comment: Your posted query doesn't have the FORMAT part, can you post your exact query?

Comment: This was actually my exact query, after reading your comment, I added `FORMAT YYYY/MM/DD` and it's working !